# Is there a way to test a future event? Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

I want to test future events.

In theory, this code should work. My problem is that when I set my date to `2020-12-25` it says Timestamp out of bounds. Is it a problem in the code or it uses some Time Zone system? I also have disabled the auto Time Zone. So please, tell me how can I test this. In my opinion, it's working, because it's executing the first condition which is `if (d < d1) { ... }`. The only thing I can't understand is if it's going to switch the conditions.

```
var config = require("./config.js");
var Twit = require('twit');
var TT = new Twit(config);

var d = new Date();
var d1 = new Date('2020-12-25');
var d2 = new Date('2020-12-26');
var d3 = new Date('2020-12-27');

console.log(d, d.getDate()); // output: 2020-12-11T08:55:45.619Z, 11
console.log(d1, d1.getDate()); // output:2020-12-25T00:00:00.000Z, 25
console.log(d2, d2.getDate()); // output:2020-12-26T00:00:00.000Z, 26
console.log(d3, d3.getDate()); // output:2020-12-27T00:00:00.000Z, 27

if (d < d1) { 
  var calc = d1.getDate() - d.getDate();
    var tweet = calc + " days left until Christmas! Ho Ho Ho!❄⛄"
     }
 else if(d >= d1 && d < d2) { 
     var tweet = "Today is Christmas! Ho Ho Ho!❄⛄ "
  }
    else if(d >= d2 && d < d3) {
        var tweet = "Today is also Christmas! Ho Ho Ho! ❄⛄"
    }
     //else { console.log(tweet);}

tweetIt();
setInterval(tweetIt, 86400000)

function tweetIt(){

TT.post('statuses/update', {status: tweet}, tweeted);

function tweeted(err, data, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log('Success: ' + data.text);
      //console.log(response);
    }
  };
  
}


tweetIt();
setInterval(tweetIt, 86400000)

function tweetIt(){

TT.post('statuses/update', {status: tweet}, tweeted);

function tweeted(err, data, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log('Success: ' + data.text);
      //console.log(response);
    }
  };
  
}
```

Comment: we usually use cron jobs and not `setInterval`

Comment: @Ifaruki Thank you, but I that means I have to redo my code! Also for the `setInterval`, I made it that way, because it seemed the easiest to me, but still thank you!

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps:
If you happen to be using JS, say to create a Node.js version of another application, remember php Time() does NOT equal js Date.now()
For the timestamp in this case you need to use Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000).

also this might be stupid but please check the time format:
2020-12-25 (make sure its y-m-d) maybe its set to (y-d-m) or something else.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, @AmanShankar! Your code didn't exactly work for me, but it gave me a rough idea of what I should do. I did it by setting an exact date and from there everything worked, thank you very much!